# LINQ Group By and NOT in

Tags: linq

I have a schema like below (it's a simplified example so please ignore the obvious schema issues):

```
table Books
{
    string bookId
}

table students_books
{
    string studentname
    string bookId
}
```

The intent is to find out books read less than 500 times.  Unfortunately I cannot keep that count in the books table.

I am writing a query like this:

```
from book in Books
    where !(from student in students_books
        group student by student.bookId into GroupedPerStudent
        where GroupedPerStudent.Count() >= 500 
        select new { bookname = GroupedPerStudent.Key }).Contains(book.bookid)
    select book
```

I am getting a compilation error on `Contains()`.  What is wrong with the query?

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Your nested query is selecting an anonymous type - you should be selecting the book ID:

```
from book in Books
  where !(from student in students_books
          group student by student.bookId into GroupedPerStudent
          where GroupedPerStudent.Count() >= 500 
          select GroupedPerStudent.Key).Contains(book.bookid)
select book;
```

but I would express it in a more positive way - and actually with two separate statements to keep it clearer:

```
var rarelyRead = from student in student_books
                 group student by student.bookId into grouped
                 where grouped.Count() < 5000
                 select grouped.Key;

var query = Books.Where(book => rarelyRead.Contains(book.book_id));
```

EDIT: Or, as per Snowbear's suggestion, using a join, which we'll use with a query continuation for fun:

```
var query = from student in student_books
            group student by student.bookId into grouped
            where grouped.Count() < 5000
            select grouped.Key into rarelyRead
            join book in Books on rarelyRead equals book.book_id
            select book;
```

Comment: Eh, didn't know that you can continue querying like that. Though I personally do not like this syntax anyway.

Comment: @jonskeet, playing compiler for a moment, it looks like your `group .. by grouped` is missing another expression and an `into` before 'grouped', but otherwise you're spot-on.

Comment: @devgeezer: Have another look now - I think it's there.

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting anonymous type in your nested query, replace it with `select GroupedPerStudent.Key`:

```
   ...
   where GroupedPerStudent.Count() >= 500 
         select GroupedPerStudent.Key).Contains(book.bookid)
```

Though I would rewrite the entire query:

```
var popularBooks = students_books
                      .GroupBy(b => b.bookId)
                      .Where(g => g.Count() >= 500)
                      .Join(Books, students_book => students_book.Key, b => b.bookId,
                                  (students_books, book) => book);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Can you please let me know whats the difference between the two queries ?

Comment: @user, the difference is that in your query you have nested subquery which is more difficult to read comparing to my query which can be read line-by-line. My second query is actually the same as last one in Jon's answer but written using `Enumerable` methods while he used Linq syntax to write a query. I would say that if you like Linq syntax you should use second or third Jon's query, otherwise use my second query.